# Как получить диапазон видимых строк в таблице LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx

Приветствую!
В таблице libgdx делаю подкачку фото с сервера. Реализовал загрузку сверху вниз, но хочу оптимизировать и сделать подгрузку только той части строк, что видна на экране в скролле у пользователя. Можно как-то получить этот диапазон средствами libgdx или надо что-то придумывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за вариант, удалось решить проще на клиенте.
Рассчитываю смещение прокрутки в eventListener

```
scrollY = scrollpane.getVisualScrollY()
```

Вычисляю актеров, попадающих в область прокрутки и отправляю запрос на
сервер для их подкачки.

Answer (score 0):

Насчёт готового решения для LIBGDX не знаю.
Но, но можно в ручную это организовать.

К примеру, получить высоту видимой области для вывода строк, поделить на высоту строки - получим кол-во строк, которое умещается в видимой области.

Ну, а дальше уже отправлять на сервер запрос с параметром `per_page`, в котором будет указанно кол-во фото для подгрузки. Соответственно на стороне сервере учесть параметр `per_page`.